# what is the difference between She is a very beautiful girl and She is very beautiful girl?

Tags: grammar, meaning

1.She is very beautiful girl

2.She is a very beautiful girl

Please explain any grammatical difference and colloquial meaning  between these two sentences.

Comment: A singular countable noun must be preceded by a determiner. So, your first sentence is incorrect.

Comment: "She is very beautiful girl" is the sort of thing that comedy Russians say in TV shows or movies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. is not grammatical English (though we immediately understand what it means). 'Girl' is a singular countable noun, which usually needs a word like 'a' (as in this sentence), 'the', 'this', 'that' etc.